# WoocCommerce - How to force update all products after import

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce, product

I recently imported large number of products into WordPress with new prices. All works fine, except price is imported. Price changed only on 1 language, until I click on every product "update" button. I have 20k products and this is not a solution...

How to automatically update all of my products 1 by 1 (because server cannot handle too big requests).

Comment: Maybe one solution is to increase the PHP and WordPress memory limit and try it again.

Comment: Just **clear products transient** going to `Woocommerce` > `Status` > `Tools` *(tab)* and on **"WooCommerce transients"**, just click on **"Clear transients"** button. **You are done and all product cached data will be updated.**

Comment: Didn't help. It is not because of cache.

Answer (score 1):

```
// reset transients for products
if (function_exists('wc_delete_product_transients')) {
    wc_delete_product_transients();
} else {
    global $woocommerce;
    $woocommerce->clear_product_transients();
}
```

To make this automatic - Try adding this code to run once your import is over. ( *Either adding once to  functions.php or any plugin* )

For WP All import, it seems There is no action/filter after import.
Try this work around

```
function fn_woocommerce_delete_product_transients($post_id) {

    $product_object = new WC_Product($post_id);
    $product_object->save();
}

add_action('woocommerce_delete_product_transients', 'fn_woocommerce_delete_product_transients', 10, 1);
```

You may try this [WooCommerce import export](https://wordpress.org/plugins/product-import-export-for-woo/) plugin as well

Comment: Didn't help. It is not because of cache.

Comment: @SergeiIzzi Which import plugin - or default WooCommerce importer?

Comment: @SergeiIzzi There will be some after import hook - In that u can just call product save function- let me check if I can get the code

Comment: Ok, I will be waiting for your answer.

Comment: @SergeiIzzi Updated the answer

Comment: transients = db cache?

My problem appears not because of transients. I cleared them many times. I just need to initialize update of all products.

1) In the admin dashboard, select Products -> All products
2) Select all the products (tick them)
3) Click the down arrow next to 'Bulk Actions' and select edit
4) Press "update" button

But i need to do it automatically and server has to handle request (not more than 5 products per update).